# Using Recursive CTE with GroupBy

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am new to the recursive CTE concept and a problem at hand, I got a tiny feeling that the problem can be solved by using recursive CTE. Let me know what you guys think.

Two tables:

Table one is a self referencing Location table with `ID`, `ParentID`, `Level` and `Description`.

Table two is an asset table which records individual assets and has a foreign key to Location table `ID` field.

```
Table1:
ID   Description ParentID  Level
1    Site1       NULL      1
2    Site2       NULL      1
3    Building1   1         2
4    Building2   1         2
5    Floor1      3         3
6    Floor2      3         3
7    Floor3      4         3
8    Place1      5         4
9    Place2      7         4

Table2:
ID  Description  Quantity  LocationID
1   Desk         3         8
2   Lamp         1         8
3   PC           10        9
```

I would like to create a stored procedure with a input parameter of `@Level` and returns all the Location records at that level and the number of assets within the location (including sub levels).

For example, if @Level = 3, the stored procedure should return:

```
ID  Description  AssetCount
5   Floor1       4   
6   Floor2       0
7   Floor3       10
```

If @Level = 2, the stored procedure should return:

```
ID Description AssetCount
3  Building1   4    
4  Building2   10
```

If the problem is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need to do something recursively. Isn't what you're asking equivalent to `select a.ID, a.Description, b.Quantity as AssetCount from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id where a.level = @level`?

Comment: @Xedni It is not. The recursion is needed to get the child rows for each parent; your example query would only sum the quantities for the parent ids and not include the children.

Comment: Xedni thanks for the suggestion, but i think jpw is right and the answer provided by JamesZ is correct and it is such an elegant way of getting the results! I could only think of ways of using temp tables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, nothing special here, just a recursive CTE joined with the other table, and the results are what you expected:

```
declare @level int = 3

;with CTE as (
  select id as origid, id, Description, parentid
  from table1 where level = @level
union all
  select CTE.origid, t1.id, CTE.Description, t1.parentid
  from CTE join table1 t1 on
  CTE.id = t1.parentid
)

select origid, CTE.description, isnull(sum(t2.Quantity),0) as Quantity
from CTE left outer join table2 t2 on CTE.id = t2.locationid
group by origid, CTE.description
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91e2c/1)

Comment: It seems resolved issue, but I'd still not prefer to use recursive CTE, you can have a look [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/)

Comment: @TirthakShah To be able to do this without recursion you'll have to have a fixed number of levels and join the table with itself separately for each level -- and for performance you'd probably have to create separate branch for each of the level parameters to get rid of the extra table